# Cross building ICU (from Conan) for Windows with Clang-CL

Tags: c++, clang, cross-compiling, icu, conan

I'm having some trouble building the ICU recipes from Conan using Clang-CL.

I'm compiling [this project](https://github.com/RobertTheSable/sable-text-converter/blob/master/conanfile.py) on Linux using the following host profile:

```
{% set msvc_install_root = os.getenv("HOME") + "/.cmake/toolchains/msvc" %}
{% set toolchain_path = os.getenv("HOME") + "/.cmake/toolchains/clang-cl-msvc.cmake" %}
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=clang
compiler.cppstd=17
compiler.version=15
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_version=v143
os=Windows
[buildenv]
CC=clang-cl
CXX=clang-cl
LD=lld
INCLUDE={{ msvc_install_root }}/vc/tools/msvc/14.34.31933/include;{{ msvc_install_root }}/kits/10/include/10.0.22621.0/shared;{{ msvc_install_root }}/kits/10/include/10.0.22621.0/ucrt;{{ msvc_install_root }}/kits/10/include/10.0.22621.0/um;{{ msvc_install_root }}/kits/10/include/10.0.22621.0/winrt
LIB={{ msvc_install_root }}/vc/tools/msvc/14.34.31933/lib/x64;{{ msvc_install_root }}/kits/10/lib/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/x64;{{ msvc_install_root }}/kits/10/lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64
[conf]
tools.microsoft.msbuild:installation_path=
tools.gnu:host_triplet=x86_64-pc-windows
tools.build:exelinkflags=["-fuse-ld=lld"]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:user_toolchain=["{{ toolchain_path }}"]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja
[options]
icu/*:shared=False
sable-text-converter/*:build_asar=False
sable-text-converter/*:use_system_boost=True
sable-text-converter/*:use_system_icu=False
```

msvc_install_root is a copy of the MSVC toolchain installed using [these scripts](https://github.com/mstorsjo/msvc-wine).

I've tried different versions of the ICU recipe, but they all fail at this step:

```
checking for namespace support... no
configure: error: Namespace support is required to build ICU.

icu/74.2: ERROR: 
Package '630871f36df7e455b54deb89876e2fe1e57d5653' build failed
```

Any idea what I could do to fix this?

Edit: Here's the error from config.log:

```
configure:6848: checking for namespace support
configure:6867: clang-cl -o conftest  -std=c++17 -MD -O3 -FS  -DNDEBUG -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION  -fuse-ld=lld conftest.cpp  >&5
clang: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-std=c++17' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-O3' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
configure:6867: $? = 0
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "ICU"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "International Components for Unicode"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "70.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "ICU 70.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://icu-project.org/bugs"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://icu-project.org"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define SIZEOF_VOID_P 8
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| namespace x_version {void f(){}}
|     namespace x = x_version;
|     using namespace x_version;
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| f();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6876: result: no
configure:6880: error: Namespace support is required to build ICU.
```

So the issue appears to be configure passing invalid flags.

Comment: Shameless plug: my [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) compiles this more or less out of the box (I had to add a few missing standard `#include`s, and change one line of code to support cxxopts3 as opposed to cxxopts2), but it uses clang+mingw (not clang-cl), and the libraries are prebuilt ones from msys2, not from conan.

Comment: I'd imagine that the configure step will have logged what it did and what the problem was when it decided namespaces weren't supported. Check the package's build directory

Comment: @AlanBirtles Added. Seems to be that ICU is passing invalid arguments. Or maybe it's trying to run the executable? I tried to compile the test manually and didn't see it failed, even with the invalid flags.

Comment: Yes, doesn't look like it understands that it needs to use msvc style command line arguments

Comment: Or it might be Conan setting the arguments as you've set `compiler=clang`, it thinks you're using clang

Comment: I'm not sure which compiler setting is the "canonical" one in this use case(clang-cl on Linux). Using msvc usually short-circuits the build, but can cause issues with some packages that don't have compatible prebuilt packages in my experience.

Comment: I understand that this is only an ``icu`` package recipe problem? All other recipes, other from ConanCenter are working fine? Using dependencies that use different build systems (CMake, Autotools, etc)? Or does the setup also fails for other autotools ones? If it fails for other recipes, it might be worth reporting and investigating in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using compiler=msvc in my profile to get my dependencies, which avoids needing to build ICU altogether. This causes issues with another of my dependencies (Boost locale), but I was able to [alter the recipe](https://gitlab.com/robertsstuff/conan-hacks/-/tree/main/boost) to work around the issues. And in the end, I can probably afford to remove the dependency on Boost since I'm not using anything that ICU doesn't provide on its own.